Best direction of air flow in peltier based air dehumidifier?
I'm currently designing a peltier element based air dehumidifier and need to decide which direction of air flow trough the device makes more sense. The possibilities are either directing the intake air from the hot side of the peltier element to the cold side or the other way round.
The concept looks like this:

Benefits i see directing the air from the cold to the hot side:

The hot side gets cooled (doesn't get hot as quick)
?

But also have seen dehumidifiers working in the other direction.
Missing the detailed thermodynamic reasoning/understanding to decide which direction is the more efficient/better one.
